# Get the correct position of a point in AndroidPlot

Tags: android, androidplot

I am trying to get the pixel position of a values in my AndroidPlot, but I can't get it to work. The idea is to place the cursor at the exact point showed on the plot, at specific terms. Did any of you encounter/solve a similar problem?

Regards
Jesper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better built-in solution, but here's a manual approach.
The following code places the cursor at the X coordinate where the user touched the screen and the corresponding Y coordinate of the first data series of the plot.

```
//NOTE about XYPlotZoomPan: when an OnTouchListener is set, zooming is disabled. Subclass to avoid it.
mPlot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        float touchX = me.getX();
        float touchY = me.getY();
        XYGraphWidget widget = mPlot.getGraphWidget();
        RectF gridRect = widget.getGridRect();
        if(gridRect.contains(touchX, touchY)){ //Check the touch event is in the grid
            XYSeries xyData = mPlot.getSeriesSet().iterator().next();
            long targetValX = Math.round(widget.getXVal(touchX));
            Log.d(TAG, "Touched at " + touchX + ", " + touchY + ". Target val X: " + targetValX);
            Long targetValY = null; 
            Long prevValX = null;
            if(mPlot.getSeriesSet().size() > 1){
                Log.w(TAG, "More than one series in plot. Using only the first one");
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < xyData.size(); ++i){
                long currValX = xyData.getX(i).longValue();
                long currValY = xyData.getY(i).longValue();
                //Calculate the range value of the closest domain value (assumes xyData is sorted in ascending X order)
                if(currValX >= targetValX){
                    long currDiff = currValX - targetValX; 
                    if(prevValX != null && (targetValX - prevValX) < currDiff){
                        targetValY = xyData.getY(i-1).longValue();
                    }else{
                        targetValY = currValY;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                prevValX = currValX;
            }
            if(targetValY != null){
                long maxValY = mPlot.getCalculatedMaxY().longValue();
                long minValY = mPlot.getCalculatedMinY().longValue();
                float pixelPosY = gridRect.top + ValPixConverter.valToPix(
                        (double)targetValY, (double)minValY, (double)maxValY, (float)gridRect.height(), true);
                widget.setRangeCursorPosition(pixelPosY);
                widget.setDomainCursorPosition(touchX);
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Domain cursor set at Y %.2f, val %.2f = %d, min-maxValY (%d, %d)",
                        pixelPosY,
                        widget.getRangeCursorVal(), targetValY,
                        minValY, maxValY));
            }else{
                Log.w(TAG, "Couldn't find the closest range to the selected domain coordinate");
            }
            mPlot.invalidate();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Touched outside the plot grid");
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want the cursor over the number, use `widget.setCursorPosition(ValPixConverter.valToPix(targetValX, targetValY, gridRect, xyData.getX(0), xyData.getX(xyData.size()-1), minValY, maxValY);));` instead of the 2 calls to `widget.setRangeCursorPosition()` and `widget.setDomainCursorPosition()`

Answer (score 2):

i`ve found a solution. My intent was to find the value for a given pixel (for example by tapping on the plot, i wanted the representing value).
So, after a bit of searching i found the helper-class ValPixConverter.
It provides a few methods that fit my needs. Unfortunately there is no documentation of the methods, but i found a solution:

```
    private float pixelToValueY(float y) {
    //Parameters: 1=input y-value, 2=minmal y-value that is shown,  3=maximal y-value that is shown, 4=Hight of the view, 5=flip
    return (float) ValPixConverter.pixToVal(y, minXY.y, maxXY.y, mySimpleXYPlot.getHeight(), false);
    }

    private float pixelToValueX(float x) {
    //Parameters: 1=input y-value, 2=minmal y-value that is shown,  3=maximal y-value that is shown, 4=Hight of the view, 5=flip
    return (float) ValPixConverter.pixToVal(x, minXY.x, maxXY.x, mySimpleXYPlot.getWidth(), false);
    }
```

You need just the other way. The method valToPix() will do this. It`s then very similar with the Code above.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated solution

I tried to follow rbarriuso approach but I found it outdated and overly complicated.

Using rbarriuso answer as a guide I came up with the following:

```
private void placeMarkerOnGraph(XYPlot plot, XYSeries plotSeries, XValueMarker xMarker, YValueMarker yMarker, float touchX, float touchY) {
    if(plot.getRegistry().getSeriesList().contains(plotSeries)) {
        if (plot.getGraph().getGridRect().contains(touchX, touchY)) {
            int targetValX = plot.screenToSeriesX(touchX).intValue();
            int targetValY = plot.screenToSeriesY(touchY).intValue();
            int threshold = (int)(plot.getBounds().getHeight().intValue() * 0.1f); //How close to a trace does the user have to click to move the markers?

            if (plotSeries.getY(targetValX).intValue() - targetValY < threshold) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Touched within threshold to trace line");
                xMarker.setValue(targetValX);
                yMarker.setValue(plotSeries.getY(targetValX).intValue());
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Touched outside graph");
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Plot does not contain series provided");
    }
}
```

### How it works

Step 1. Check if you actually touched inside the graph

Step 2. Convert from touch cords to screen graph coords

Step 3. Take the X value (that has been converted into graph coords) and find its Y value

Step 4. If you touched close enough to the trace move the marker/cursor

### Other hints

- I use markers in my example instead of cursors as there's no limit to how many markers a plot can have but you can only have one cursor.
- The function only changes the markers position, you have to optionally format and add your marker to the plot first.
- XYSeries now uses number so use the necessary values for example: if your series goes from `0.0f` to `1.0f` use `.floatValue()`
- Nothing will visually change until you use `plot.redraw()`
- Threshold is a percentage of the plots total height to take into account zooming

### A more advanced solution

The first solution works alright for graphs that aren't very steep, but otherwise it doesn't have a lot of accuracy because it fails to take into account data points that aren't directly below where the user touched on the graph.

Below I've added a more beefy solution that relies on a for-loop but is much more accurate. The operation of how it works is pretty similar to the first solution.

```
private void placeMarkerOnGraph(XYPlot plot, XYSeries plotSeries, XValueMarker xMarker, YValueMarker yMarker, float touchX, float touchY) {
    if(plot.getRegistry().getSeriesList().contains(plotSeries)) {
        if (plot.getGraph().getGridRect().contains(touchX, touchY)) {
            int targetValX = plot.screenToSeriesX(touchX).intValue();
            int targetValY = plot.screenToSeriesY(touchY).intValue();
            int threshold = (int)(plot.getBounds().getWidth().intValue() * 0.1f); //How close to a trace does the user have to click to move the markers?
            Integer closestValue = null;
            Integer xPos = null;
            Integer yPos = null;

            for(int i = targetValX - threshold; i < targetValX + threshold; i++){
                //If the user touches near either end of the graph we need to make sure we don't go out of the arrays bounds
                if(i > 0 && i < graphSize) {
                    int closeness = Math.abs(Math.abs(plotSeries.getY(i).intValue() - targetValY) + Math.abs(i - targetValX));
                    Log.d(TAG,"Distance to nearest trace: " + closeness);
                    if ((closestValue != null && closeness < closestValue) || (closestValue == null && closeness < threshold)) {
                        closestValue = closeness;
                        xPos = i;
                        yPos = plotSeries.getY(i).intValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (xPos != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Touched within threshold");
                xMarker.setValue(xPos);
                yMarker.setValue(yPos);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Touched outside threshold");
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Touched outside graph");
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Plot does not contain series provided");
    }
}
```