# AndroidPlot Remove cursor from plot

Tags: cursor, androidplot

thanks to this post :

[Get the correct position of a point in AndroidPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488532/get-the-correct-position-of-a-point-in-androidplot)

i manage to display a cursor near a point of my plot.

Now i want to remove this cursor from the plot.

First question : How can i do that ?

Second question  : I found a trick not to see it by displaying it in a non visible area of the plot (-1,-1) But i can't update this in a long press event click on the ploy. Although i manage to do this in a button click. Is there an explanation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, in version 0.9.6 and later, you can disable the cursor(s) by setting the corresponding paint element to null:

```
plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainCursorPaint(null);
plot.getGraphWidget().setRangeCursorPaint(null);
```

As far as your second question goes, it's hard to say without seeing some code.  You should create a separate question for that though.