# AndroidPlot get Y-Position of Line

Tags: android, position, androidplot

I would like to place a `TextLabelWidget` above a specific line in android Plot.

**Is there any way to connect it directly to a line or to calculate the exact Y-position of an line.**

[Get the correct position of a point in AndroidPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488532/get-the-correct-position-of-a-point-in-androidplot)

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/87452134?noredirect=1

That's my Code so far:

```
TextLabelWidget txtText = new TextLabelWidget(
                    rdPuls.getLayoutManager(),
                    "Some Text",
                    null,  // TextLabelWidget instances "pack" to wrap the actual text size
                    TextOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
            txtText.getLabelPaint().setColor(getColor(R.color.biosign_green));
            txtText.getLabelPaint().setTextSize(PixelUtils.dpToPix(15));
            txtText.position(
                    // add a right margin of 4dp:
                    0, PixelUtils.dpToPix(80)

                    // center the text with the plot space vertically:
                    PixelUtils.dpToPix(80), VerticalPositioning.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM,

                    // use the middle of the right edge of the text widget as the anchor:
                    Anchor.RIGHT_MIDDLE);
```

Picture:

[image]

Comment: is the "someText" line from the image in the second link what you are trying to reproduce here?

Comment: @Nick Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show a straight line with some text, you can use one of the subclasses of `XYValueMarker`:

```
YValueMarker marker = new YValueMarker(35, "someText");
plot.addMarker(marker);

// later, if you want to dynamically move it around: (dont forget 
// to call plot.redraw() if you do though)
marker.setValue(34);
```

You can use the alternative constructors or `marker.setTextPosition(...)` to control exactly where the text appears.

Comment: Can I change the padding between line and text?

Comment: Not currently.  It would be an easy thing to add though.  Feel free to submit a feature request.  You could also extend XYGraphWidget and override the drawMarkers method.

Comment: plot, gridRect and drawText are private can you change this or add getters for both?

Comment: @Franzi `XYGraphWidget.drawMarkerText(...)` is `protected` in the upcoming 1.5.5 release.  That should make things a little simpler