# Androidplot - getSeriesSet() and other methods in newer AndroidPlot versions

Tags: androidplot

I'm looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18644240/11997596) from another question and trying to test it out.

One problem I'm having is a couple of the methods seem to have changed in newer versions of Androidplot. For whatever reason I can't figure out what replacement methods I'm meant to use.

The methods in question are:

- mPlot.getSeriesSet().iterator().next() //Cannot resolve getSeriesSet
- ValPixConverter.valToPix //Cannot resolve ValPixConverter
- widget.getXVal //Cannot resolve .getXVal

My ultimate goal is to be able to place markers on the graph traces

**EDIT:**

Ok I've figured getXVal/getYVal gets replaced with screenToSeriesX/screenToSeriesY, the rest are still unknown :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out :)

`mPlot.getSeriesSet().iterator().next()` gets replaced with `plot2.getRegistry().getSeriesList().iterator().next()`

`getXVal` & `getYVal` gets replaced with `screenToSeriesX` & `screenToSeriesY`

For `ValPixConverter` I just copied the class from an older version of Androidplot.

This was enough to get me playing around with placing markers/cursor on the graph but a better solution will be formulated for the future.